# How can I get the data passed from the ajax in Django?

Tags: python, ajax, django

How can I get the data passed from the ajax in Django?

In the js, I use ajax to pass the data:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'/app_admin/myServerDetail/',
    data:JSON.stringify({'server_id':server_id}),  // I want to pass the server_id to views.py
    dataType:'json',
    success:success_func
})
```

In my views.py, I print the request.POST, and server_id:

```
server_id = request.POST.get("server_id")
print (server_id, request.POST)
```

The result is bellow:

```
(None, <QueryDict: {u'{"server_id":"f55dbe56-7fa8-4d13-8e1e-2dc67499b6ac"}': [u'']}>)
```

So, how can I get the server_id in my views.py ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try changing this `data:JSON.stringify({'server_id':server_id})`
```

to this `data:{'server_id':server_id}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the json stringifyed data passed by ajax like your case, you should use json to loads the request.body.

```
server_id = json.loads(request.body).get("server_id")
```